# PagerTabStrip Activity cannot instantiate the type PagerAdapter

Tags: android-layout, adapter, swipe

Please, can you help me with an issue?

I'm doing an application that uses pagerStrips, and I have read in a blog this code:

(In few words, it uses different fragments for every `pageStrip`, in this case it has 3 different strips, so it has three different layouts).

```
package com.tabs;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;

public class Testi extends FragmentActivity {

// list contains fragments to instantiate in the viewpager
  List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
  List<String> fragmentTitles = new Vector<String>();
  // page adapter between fragment list and view pager
  private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
  // view pager
  private ViewPager mViewPager;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        getSupportFragmentManager();
        // creating fragments and adding to list
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Page1Fragment.class.getName()));
        fragmentTitles.add(Page1Fragment.class.getSimpleName());
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Page2Fragment.class.getName()));
        fragmentTitles.add(Page2Fragment.class.getSimpleName());
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Page3Fragment.class.getName()));
        fragmentTitles.add(Page3Fragment.class.getSimpleName());

        this.mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(),     fragments, fragmentTitles);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        View pagerStrip = findViewById(R.id.pagerTabStrip);
        if (pagerStrip instanceof PagerTabStrip) {
                PagerTabStrip pagerTabStrip = (PagerTabStrip) pagerStrip;
                pagerTabStrip.setDrawFullUnderline(true);
                pagerTabStrip.setTabIndicatorColorResource(android.R.color.black);
                // pagerTabStrip.setTextColor(color.white);
        } else if (pagerStrip instanceof PagerTitleStrip) {
                PagerTitleStrip pagerTitleStrip = (PagerTitleStrip) pagerStrip;
                pagerTitleStrip.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
        }

        mViewPager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
   }

}
```

But I get error: "`Cannot instantiate the type PagerAdapter`"

```
this.mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments, fragmentTitles);.
```

Please, can you help me?

Sorry for my bad english :D

Answer (score 1):

`PagerAdapter` is an `abstract class` – you cannot instantiate it. You have to create a `new class that inherits from PagerAdapter` and use that instead.

So, for example PagerAdapter can be like

```
   public abstract class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

   // fragments to instantiate in the viewpager
   private List<Fragment> fragments;

   // constructor
   public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,List<Fragment> fragments) {
      super(fm);
      this.fragments = fragments;
   }

   // return access to fragment from position, required override
   @Override
   public Fragment getItem(int position) {
      return this.fragments.get(position);
   }

   // number of fragments in list, required override
   @Override
   public int getCount() {
      return this.fragments.size();
   }

}
```

Note: In imports `PagerAdapter` should be your own. It's not `import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

PagerAdapter is an abstract class you must implement. Impelement abstract methods in a derived class or use one of available classes i.e. FragmentPagerAdapter or FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new implementation of PagerAdapter, you can also use the built in FragmentPagerAdapter (built for this use-case) like so:

```
        final List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<>();
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentOne.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentTwo.class.getName()));

        PagerAdapter adapter = new FragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()) {
            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                return fragments.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return fragments.size();
            }
        };
        final ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
```